# kc_idp_hint from a SAML Client

Tags: keycloak

Has anyone had success leveraging kc_idp_hint from a SAML Client? If you have, could you share the secret sauce? I'm not sure if I'm beating a dead horse attempting kc_idp_hint with a SAML Client.

Comment: This might sound obvious, but did you try adding kc_idp_hint=<Your IDP alias> in the SAML client request?

Comment: Unfortunately, I also don't know. Probably you are had a look at https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/using-kc-idp-hint-to-skip-default-idp-with-saml/4500